# Parsing string to XDocument

Tags: c#, parsing, linq-to-xml

I'm making a WP app, and it loads an xml from a URL.

So I download the content of the URL to a string using WebClient.
The string returned is then parsed using XDocument.Parse()

Thing is, when looking into the XDocument, it just tells me "Could not evaluate expression", am I doing anything wrong?

```
void DownloadInfo(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Parse(e.Result);
    }
```

Comment: Have you looked at `e.Result` and confirmed that it has xml in it?

Comment: e.Result is definitely xml :)

Comment: What do you mean when you say `...when looking into the XDocument...`?  Is this happening at a particular line of code?  If so, could you post the code?

Comment: when I break the code (or whatever it is called) http://i41.tinypic.com/a40i2s.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have a problem, you just don't know how to interpret the debugger output.

*Some* of the properties of the XDocument can't be evaluated. That doesn't mean that you don't have a valid XDocument.